# How to add data vertically while xtracting tables from web page to excel

Tags: vba, excel

My code

```
Public Sub Raju()         
    Dim alertTime As Date
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("0:05:00")        
    '
    ' mymacro Macro        
    '
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")  

     Dim usedRows As Long
     usedRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     
     With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "URL", _
                             Destination:=ws.Range(Cells(1, 1),Cells(usedRows, 1)))
     ...
End sub
```

Now table updated in horizontal direction but I need data imported vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QueryTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx) are positioned to the upper left cell of a destination range. Currently, you run QueryTables always at `(1,1)` as end bound `(usedRows, 1)` is ignored. If existing data is there, QueryTables will insert columns horizontally.

For vertical placement of data, consider adding to the one cell position:

```
Destination:=Cells(usedRows + 1, 1))
```